# How to change map style in gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, styles, gmaps4rails

I am working with gmaps4rails and was wondering if there is a way to change map style (feature, color etc) in gmaps4rails. Do i have to use json for that?

thank you,

Comment: Did you check the Wiki for Gmaps4Rails? There is a whole section for display related configuration: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki

Comment: I did, i am new to rails so the question might be easy for some, I am trying to change map style by passing array styles: [ { "stylers": [ { "hue": "#00ffff" } ] },{ } ], but it doesn't work

Comment: In <%= gmaps( :map_options => {:raw => "{}" }, 
:markers => { "data" => @json, "options" => {"draggable" => true, "list_container" => "markers_list" } }) %> to :raw hash i am trying to add: { "stylers":  { "hue": "#ff1a00" }  }, but i get blank map instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= gmaps( :map_options => {:raw => "{styles: myStyle}" }, 
           :markers     => { "data" => @json, "options" => {"draggable" => true, "list_container" => "markers_list" } }) %>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var myStyle = [ 
  { featureType: "all", stylers: [{ "hue": "#ff1a00" } ]} 
];
</script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I know this is basic, but still took me some time to figure it out.